How to commit jdbcTemplate after every query?
I have two queries
 public void batchClose(List<FatAttribute> attributes) {
        log.debug("""
                @method -> void batchClose(List<FatAttribute> attributes)
                @data -> {}
                """, attributes);
        
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
                """
                        update SAMETABLE
                        set DATE_E = ?
                        where IDI = ? and IDA = ? and IDTYPE = ?
                        and DATE_B is not null
                        and DATE_E is null
                        """,
                new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                        ps.setDate(1, sqlStringToSqlDate(breFormatToSqlFormat(attributes.get(i).getAv_dateE())));
                        ps.setLong(2, attributes.get(i).getIdi());
                        ps.setLong(3, attributes.get(i).getIda());
                        ps.setLong(4, attributes.get(i).getIdtype());
                    }

                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        return attributes.size();
                    }

                });

    }

public List<FatAttribute> massCreate(List<FatAttribute> attributes) {

    
    String s = "INSERT INTO SAMETABLE(idi, ida, idtype, nvalue, svalue, dvalue, date_b, date_e) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    if (attributes.isEmpty()) {
        return attributes;
    }

    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(s,
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setLong(1, attributes.get(i).getIdi());
                    ps.setLong(2, attributes.get(i).getIda());
                    ps.setLong(3, attributes.get(i).getIdtype());

                    if (attributes.get(i).getNvalue() == null) {
                        ps.setNull(4, Types.FLOAT);
                    } else {
                        ps.setBigDecimal(4, attributes.get(i).getNvalue());
                    }

                    if (attributes.get(i).getSvalue() == null) {
                        ps.setNull(5, Types.VARCHAR);
                    } else {
                        ps.setString(5, attributes.get(i).getSvalue());
                    }

                    if (attributes.get(i).getDvalue() == null || attributes.get(i).getDvalue().isBlank()) {
                        ps.setNull(6, Types.DATE);
                    } else {
                        ps.setDate(6, sqlStringToSqlDate(breFormatToSqlFormat(attributes.get(i).getDvalue())));
                    }

                    ps.setDate(7, sqlStringToSqlDate(breFormatToSqlFormat(attributes.get(i).getAv_dateB())));
                    ps.setNull(8, Types.DATE);
          

                }

                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return attributes.size();
                }

            });

    return searchSattrValue(attrs, attrs.get(0).getAv_dateB());

}

and I need to execute them as:
  public List<FatAttribute> massCreate(List<FatAttribute> attributes) {

        // filtering input attributes
        List<FatAttribute> opened = this.dao.searchSattrValue(attributes, null);

        if (!opened.isEmpty()) {
            dao.batchClose(opened);
        }

        // create
        return dao.massCreate(attributes);
    }

But I get an error, because SAMETABLE containe trigger on DATE_B and DATE_E (simple explanation: if date_e is null for same ida you cant insert new row with that ida and date_e null).
Method dao.batchClose exicutes, but without commit massCteate get old rows from DB.
Question is, how to commit query in method batchClose or any othe suggestion?
I've tried answers from Commit on jdbcTemplate or DataSource they doesn't work.
